# polynomial modulo for higher degree

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Given $f(x) , n, g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is usually of a small degree then if we find $h_1(x)$ such that $f(x)\equiv h_1(x)\mod \{n,g(x)\}$ ,

Is there any algorithm to find $h_2(x)$ such that $f(x)\equiv h_2(x)\mod \{n,(g(x))^r\}$ where given value of $r>1,n>2$ and $f(x),g(x),h_1(x),h_2(x)$ are all polynomials.

Also I would like to know, where can I get best knowledge on polynomial modulo where I can find basic algorithms to solve problems such as above. I mean can anyone suggest me good books.

Comment: What do you mean by $f\equiv h_2 \mod {n,g }$? I have never seen a double argument for $\mod{u,v}$.

Comment: $n$ is Integer and $g(x)$ is polynomial

Comment: that notation of double arguments , I pick it from mathematica wolfram

Comment: I know that for example, if we write $a\equiv b \mod n$ then this means that there exist $k$ such that $a=b+kn$ but if we write $a\equiv b \mod u,v$ then what does it mean?,I'm sorry I can't help here if I did not find what does it mean

Comment: open wolframalpha.com , type in "polynomialmod((x^5+3x+1)^15,{13, x^2-1})" without quotes. This is a random example.

Comment: But, typing that into wolfram alpha doesn't *explain* what the meaning is.  For example, it could mean that you're working with polynomials of degree at most 13 or it could mean that your modding by the ideal $\langle 13,x^2-1\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: In my answer I used the second one $\mathbb{Z}[x]/<n,g(x)>$ or $\mathbb{Z}/(n)[X]$

Comment: @Elaqqad: Its always great to know things properly. I understand the notation I have taken from wolframalpha. But earlier, before you have clarified , I am unaware of exact proper notation of expressing the congruence.

Comment: @Elaqqad mod $\,u,v\,$ is the congruence associated to the ideal $\,I = (u,v)\,$ in the ambient ring $R$, i.e. $\,a\equiv b\pmod{u,v}\,$ $\iff$ $ a-b\in (u,v) = u R + v R\,$ $\iff$ $\, a/I = b/I\,$ in $\,R/I.\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all , here is the meaning of the notation (a mathematician (even a student) never uses a notation which does not understand) :
$$ f \equiv h \mod \{n,g\} \iff f(x)-h(x)\equiv q(x). g(x) \mod n$$
This notation can be seen also as the definition of congruence in the ring $F_n[X]$. So we will her eliminate $n$ and say only that : Let $f,g,h_1\in F_n[X]$ such that :
$$ f(x)=h_1(x) \mod g(x) $$
(which means exactly the same thing as your first condition) can we deduce anything about :
$$f(x)\equiv h_2(x) \mod g(x)^r $$

the first thing you have to know is that $h_2$ contain a lot of information compared to $h_1$ because $g^r$ has a large degree than $g$ which means that even if we have $h_1$ we have to do a large number of operations in order to obtain $h_2$, in the following lines I will describe a method to obtain $h_2$.

In order to use $h_1$ we can write:
$$h_2(x)=a_0(x)+a_1(x)g(x)+\cdots+a_{r-1}(x)g(x)^{r-1} $$

with $a_0(x)=h_1(x)$ and you can compute $a_1(x)$ as:
$$f_1(x)=\frac{f(x)-a_0(x)}{g(x)}\equiv a_1(x) \mod g(x)  $$

and you can continue :
$$f_2(x)=\frac{f_1(x)-a_1(x)}{g(x)}\equiv a_2(x) \mod g(x)  $$
$$f_3(x)=\frac{f_2(x)-a_2(x)}{g(x)}\equiv a_3(x) \mod g(x)  $$
and so on ( repeat $r$ times)

This is "an algorithm" but I don't know if it's the minimal one,The only thing I can tell and that you have to understand is the fact that even if you have given $h_1(x)$ you have to do a lot of calculus in order to compute $h_2(x)$